# How do I reset an iterator in Java?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, hashset

Below, I have an iterator for a collection named `Sigma`. How do I reset the iterator to its first element when the `while` loop completes?

```
Iterator it = Sigma.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    letter = (String)it.next();
    System.out.println(letter);
}
```

Comment: I think you should not. To reset, just get a new iterator from the underlying data structure. `Iterator` is an interface only provides 3 methods, `hasNext`, `next` and `remove`.

Comment: hey guys, you are really not solving the problem by requesting new Iterator from the underlying data structure, you are just escaping from the problem in this case, what would happen if the underlying data structure has been changed since the last time we get an Iterator??

Comment: and OP, why do you need to reset the Iterator?? to iterate over it again?? just do what you want to do in single loop, why splitting it over 2 loops??

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill *"what would happen if the underlying data structure has been changed since the last time we get an Iterator??"* I think you are imagining that the iterator stores a snapshot of the state of the collection when it is created, but for most collections, including OP's `HashSet`, that's not so. It reads directly from the collection, and it is invalid to add or remove any values during iteration, with the single exception of removing the currently iterated value through the `Iterator.remove()` method, so any other modifications are a non-issue, as you are not allowed to do them.

Comment: @Boann i'm not imaginating, i'm talking in general way, if Iterator stores a snapshot or not, this is an implementation details.

Answer (score 9):

Iterators don't have a reset method, and don't need one. Collections are not like a cassette tape that you need to rewind. You can simply abandon old iterators.

Every time you call `.iterator()`, the collection will return a new iterator which starts at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much work with Iterators but I'm guessing you could set the iterator to its original state.

```
Iterator it =  Sigma.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    letter= (String) it.next();
    System.out.println(letter);
}

it =  Sigma.iterator();
```

Comment: That's not setting Iterator to its original state, that's requesting new iterator from Sigma, if Sigma values didn't change its okey, but what it already changed? (new values added or removed from Sigma), you will get new Iterator with different values.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill That's a very good point. I suppose the only solution would be to create a deep copy of Sigma at the start and then use that for iteration.

Comment: @RayondKelly there's many solution to this problem, you can make a resetable iterator which accepts an iterator, this resetable iterator will firstly iterate over the supplied iterator, coping each object iteration to an internal array, then when reseting, it back its index to the first (an inefficient way), another simple way, just insure that the underlying data structure doesn't change, in case of collection you can force this behavoir by decorating the class by Collections.unmodifiableXXX methods, of course may exist other solutions :)